# insert into with variable and name of the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

i am trying to make the following work:

```
declare @Variable varchar(max)
set @Variabele = 'NameOfColumn'

INSERT into EmptyTable (ID, Name, Number )
select ID, @Variable, ????
from FullTable
```

I am putting the name of a column in @Variable and want to put into EmptyTable: the ID, Name of the column, the value that is in that column

The last part isnt working with what i have tried, i keep getting the name of the column instead of the value thats in that column for that row.

Anyone have any ideas for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, specify exact DBMS you're using (I suspect it is SQL server) since answer can depend on it.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql:

```
declare @Variable varchar(max)
set @Variable = 'NameOfColumn'

declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = '
    INSERT into EmptyTable (ID, Name, Number )
    select ID, ''' + @Variable + '''' + ', ' + @Variable + '
    from FullTable'

exec sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @stmt
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to get value from column if column name stored in variable.
I hope, below code is helpful for you.

```
Declare @Variable varchar(max)
set @Variable = 'Name'

exec ( 'INSERT into EmptyTable (ID, Name, Number )
        select ID,' + @Variable + ', 0 from FullTable')
```